# C language how to fix my call function

Tags: c, arrays, function, vector

I have added a void function and an int function. The void function works just fine but the int function will not work, I have been sure to include a return since it requires one. I think this has something to do with my call in the main. What am I missing or doing wrong here? Thank for the help in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>

void multi_vec(int v1[], int v2[], int v3[], int n);

int comp_vec(int v1[], int v2[], int n);

int main(){

int n = 0;
int i = 0;

printf("Enter the length of the vectors: ");
scanf("%d",&n);

int v1[n];
int v2[n];
int v3[n];

printf("Enter the first vector: ");
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    scanf("%d",&v1[i]);
    }

printf("Enter the second vector");
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    scanf("%d",&v2[i]);
    }

multi_vec(v1, v2, v3, n);

printf("The multiplication of the vectors is: ");
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    printf("%d",v3[i]);
    printf(" ");
    }

int compare;
compare = comp_vec(v1,v2,v3,n); //this is where I think I went wrong

}

void multi_vec(int v1[], int v2[], int v3[], int n){

int i;

for(i = 0; i < n; i++){

    v3[i] = v1[i] * v2[i];

    }
}
int comp_vec(int v1[], int v2[], int v3[], int n){

int i;

for(i=0; i < n; i++){
    if(v1[i] != v2[i]){
    printf("not the same");
    return 0;
    }

    else{
    printf("are the same");
    return 0;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: Someone downvoted this question, why? It is a pretty reasonable question.

Comment: There would have been a compiler diagnostic, and you did not report that in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function declaration

```
int comp_vec(int v1[], int v2[], int n); //3 param
```

doesn't match with function definition

```
int comp_vec(int v1[], int v2[], int v3[], int n){ // 4 param
```

Comment: Wow that was silly of me, thank you for the insight before I pulled out all my hair!

Comment: @SgtOVERKILL : That happens once in a while ;-) and you're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The prototype of `comp_vec` doesn't match the definition.

The declaration:

```
int comp_vec(int v1[], int v2[], int n);
```

The definition:

```
int comp_vec(int v1[], int v2[], int v3[], int n){
```

Change the declaration to match the definition, and you should be fine.

Comment: I did not even notice that, I have upvoted your answer.